# Querying many-to-many relationship in EF Core so that result SQL query uses JOIN

Tags: .net, linq, ef-core-2.0

This seems like a trivial question but I haven't managed to find the answer yet.

I'm using EF Core. I have a simple many-to-many relationship of Students to Courses with a middle table called StudentsToCourses. I have a class for each of those 3 tables, even though I've read somewhere that only Students and Courses would suffice, but this is what I have now.

I'm trying to retrieve students for Geography course using LINQ:

```
var students = studentsRepository.GetAll()
              .Where(s => s.StudentsToCourses.Any(sc => sc.Course.Description == "Geography"))
              .ToList();
```

My query is translated to SQL using a subquery ("where exists (select 1 from..." etc.) instead of a join. How can write this query differently so that join is used? Is it possible? Current query is less efficient.

Comment: Less efficient... is this visible in the query plan, execution time etc? You could write the LINQ query with joins if it's *absolutely* necessary, but then you have to guard against duplicate results, which also takes resources/time. (there's probably one course with description "Geography" but what if you query on a property like "Level"?)

Comment: Bu I don't query on a property "Level" :) And I'd like to know if there is any option to do it with joins. If you know how, why don't you tell me?